# finding the sum of a file of numbers from the command line

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

when executing on the command line it is supposed to have python3 a4.py apple

the file whose numbers i am trying to sum looks exactly like this

```
4   14
5
```

this is what i have gathered so far

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
fp = open(sys.argv[1])
fileContents = fp.read()
fp.close()
numbers = fileContents
print(numbers)

def map(f,items):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,len(items),1):
        result = result + [f(items[i])]
    return result

a=map(eval,numbers)

def sum(num):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,len(num),1):
        total = total + i
    return total
print(sum(a))
```

Comment: Did you mean to redefine `sum` on purpose? In general it is *not* a good idea to use identifiers that Python already uses, in this case [sum()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) is already a built-in function.

Comment: the same for builtin [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I am a bit confused by the "recursion" tag)

How about this?

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
    total = 0
    for line in inf:
        total += sum(int(i) for i in line.split())

print(total)
```

*Notes*:

- this assumes that each line only contains numeric values (in this case integers)
- if your numbers contain float values, use `float()` rather than `int()`
- using `with` automatically closes the file for you when you are done or you encounter an execption.
- this processes the file line-by-line, so it will not be limited by memory issues with huge files (should that ever be a possibility)

Update:

You can shorten this even more with this provided by a helpful comment by J.F.Sebastian below:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
    print(sum(int(number) for line in inf for number in line.split()))
```

Comment: you could call sum() once: `print(sum(int(number) for line in file for number in line.split())`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I was running into problems with the nested generator expression - always gets me - so I stuck to the more "verbose" and easily comprehensible version. If you don't mind (or mean to post your own solution) I'd be happy to add your optimization to my answer with the appropriate credit.

Comment: @Levon: in what way it "gets you". Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Levon: if you copy and paste your code into the interpreter it'd generate a SyntaxError on the last line even though it's valid.  Add a blank line before `print(total)` to avoid this.

Comment: @DSM Interesting, this is a difference in how the regular Python shell and IPython handle code. When I pasted it into IPython (where I usually work) - no problem, but I just tried with the regular shell, and you are right, the blank line does make a difference.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a4test.py", line 15, in <module>
    a = map(eval,numbers)
  File "a4test.py", line 12, in map
    result = result + [f(items[i])]
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: The code I have posted doesn't use `map` .. again, please **only** copy and use the code I have posted (6 lines). *Also* please could you help declutter the comments section by deleting your older comments? Thanks.

Comment: i need to use all the code that i have to make it run... i am confused... can you dumb down what your asking for me because i am not that advanced as we can already see. i just inputted your code at the very end where i originally had the third part of my code... is that not what i was supposed to do?

Comment: or are you saying all i need is those 6 lines of code opposed to the amount i had before?

Comment: @ErinAlyse *Exactly* .. those 6 lines should take the place of your code. Those 6 lines will sum up the numbers in that file and display the total.

Comment: File "a4.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open(argv[1]) as inf:
NameError: name 'argv' is not defined
erin@ubuntu:~/cs150/exam3p/a4$

Comment: @ErinAlyse  ok, change that to `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: after i added import sys at the top of my file it owrked perfectly. thank you so very much... i was def making this harder than i needed to

Comment: @ErinAlyse Consider working through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), I would guess most people using Python have done this and gotten something valuable out of it. It would be time well spent

Comment: @ErinAlyse  Glad you got it to work, it helped when you posted the error message as it make it obvious you were mixing code. And your last error message showed the problem clearly and it was an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Levon's solution based on your example. However, if you had numbers formatted as currencies or had to extract embedded numbers, the below would serve as a base:

```
import sys
import mmap

fin = open(sys.argv[1])
mm = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
total = sum(int(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'\d+', mm))
```